# VBA to Check for Non-Specific Value in cell

Tags: excel, vba

I need excel to check to see if there is text in a cell (B4) and if there is copy and paste whatever is in cell (A4) to a new workbook. The text in (B4) will be something along the lines of 3 of 7, 4 of 9, etc but will always be changing. I don't know how to check for a value that keeps chaning or if I should just check for the cell itself.

Comment: How is the value changing? Manual Input? Formula Input? Via Code?

Comment: it is a new workbook from week to week so i need a macro that can be run with each new workbook. the value in column a will stay the same

Comment: In that case simply use `If len(trim(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B4").Value))<>0 then` to check if the cell has anything or not

Comment: can i get it to then copy and past the string in column a into another workboo?. sorry i just have no vba experience and need to automate as much as possible.

Comment: yes you can use the `cell.copy <dest>` to achieve what you want. But for that you will have to read up on VBA or try and record a macro and see how it works :)

Answer (score 0):

This macro will perform the copy and leave the **new** workbook active:

```
Sub CheckVal()
    If [B4] <> "" Then
        Set r1 = Range("A4")
        Workbooks.Add
        r1.Copy Range("A4")
    End If
End Sub
```